# How can I get the control name of a dynamic Angular field?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-formbuilder

I am trying to push new controls dynamically into my formBuilder.

```js
/* templatesTypes = ["string1", "string2", "string3","string4"] */
/* templates = [{templateType: "string1", ...}, {templateType: "string2"}, ...]*/

this.agency = this.fb.group({
  name: [],
  templates: this.fb.array([])
});

const arrayControl = this.agency.controls['templates'] as FormArray;
const objControl = {};
templatesTypes.forEach(templateType => {
  objControl[templateType] = [{
    value: templates.filter(template => template.templateType === templateType)
  }];
  arrayControl.push(this.fb.group(objControl));
});
```

```html
<div formArrayName="templates" *ngFor="let templateType of agency.get('templates').controls; let i = index">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <label>{{ templateType.name }}</label>
    <ng-select  
      [items]="agency.get('templates').controls[i]" 
      bindLabel="templateName" 
      formControlName="{{ templateType.name }}">
    </ng-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The control name is dynamic, based on the template name ("string1", "string2", ...).

But I don't found any way to get the control name dynamicaly. I try with `templateType.name` but it's return nothing.

Comment: Try this `[formControl]="agency.get('templatesMails').controls[i]"`

Comment: @NadhirFalta Try where ? And why ? I want to get the control name. Not to set a formControl into my view

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: @Kamoulox, to add controls to a FormGroup use addControl, see the docs: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `templateType` in HTML template is instanced of `AbstractControl` which does not have `name` property.

I think this code should work fine.

```
<div formArrayName="templates" *ngFor="let templateType of agency.get('templates').controls; let i = index">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <label>{{ templateType.name }}</label>
    <ng-select  
      [items]="agency.get('templates').controls[i]" 
      bindLabel="templateName" 
      formControlName="{{ templates[i].templateType }}">
    </ng-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference: 
- `AbstractControl`: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl

Comment: It's not working. I get this console error : `ERROR TypeError: "_co.templates is undefined"`

Comment: If you code haven't uncommented this, please do so. 
`/* templatesTypes = ["string1", "string2", "string3","string4"] */`
`/* templates = [{templateType: "string1", ...}, {templateType: "string2"}, ...]*/`

Comment: It's the trick, use array templates instead formBuilder to get the control name. Thanks